# Ethernet devices over wifi

Tags: wireless-router, ethernet

I have  a CCTV DVR which communicates over standard ethernet or LAN, a TP-LINK wifi router and a computer. I want to access the video data from the DVR through the wifi of the router without internet. I am new to networking. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: *"i have a CCTV DVR ,which communicates over standard ethernet or LAN"* -- Is this actually a network connection, or just a connection that uses CAT5 cables (aka "ethernet" cable), and has nothing to do with networking or Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

If the DVR doesn't have wifi and you can't run a cable to your router then you'll need to get an ethernet to wifi adapter, such as [this one](https://www.iogear.com/product/GWU627/)

You'd connect it to your wifi network then just connect your ethernet device to it with a short ethernet cable.